# Set covering SOTA methods and benchmarks

Tags: benchmark, set-covering

I want to compare different methods for Set Covering problem. So I have 2 questions:

1. what are the best methods for solving this problem (precise and not precise methods)
2. what are the most common benchmark datasets for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The instances from the literature are available here:
[http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/orlib/scpinfo.html](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/%7Emastjjb/jeb/orlib/scpinfo.html)

Note that the set covering problem is a quite fundamental problem that can appear in various contexts leading to very different instances. The instances from the literature might not represent well this diversity.

Many set covering problems are well solved by basic integer linear programming.

Other approaches from the literature are

- Lagrangian heuristics: A. Caprara, M. Fischetti, and P. Toth, “A Heuristic Method for the Set Covering Problem,” [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.47.5.730)
- Local search heuristics: M. Yagiura, M. Kishida, and T. Ibaraki, “A 3-flip neighborhood local search for the set covering problem” [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2004.10.018)

Comment: Thank you. The reason, why I'm interested in something except ILP solver is that according to my humble experience sometimes ILP solver works worse than special methods. I tried some set covering instances from MIPLIB benchmark and some open (i.e. unsolved) problems are very difficult for general ILP solver . I'm interested in this topic because for similar Maximum Independent Set problem  there are some other SOTA methods (KAMIS) that generally works better than ILP solvers, so I'm curious about special methods for Set cover.

Comment: ILP solvers are able to find the optimal solution in less than a second of some set covering instances where other algorithms can't find them at all. As I mentioned in the answer, set covering instances are very diverse. KaMIS implements a branch-and-reduce algorithm. As far as I know, no successful branch-and-reduce algorithm as been proposed for the set covering problem.